# Вывожу данные из базы в виде <table>. Как по dblclick превращать <td> в <input> и обратно (для быстрого обновления значений)?

Tags: javascript, html, table

Всем привет! Я вывожу данные из базы. Некоторые значения нужно оперативно обновлять. Хотел по событию `ondblclick` превращать `<td>` в `input` c `value` равным значению `<td>`. Затем по событию onchange input превращать снова в `<td>` с обновленным значением (соответственно база тоже обновится). Меня больше интересует именно метаморфоза td-input и обратно. Как это сделать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У браузеров есть простой путь для редактирования ячеек: попробуйте для этих целей установить атрибут [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B/contenteditable)

для активации режима редактирования

```
<td contenteditable="true">
```

для деактивации режима редактирования

```
<td contenteditable="false">
```

PS: если это необходимо сделать при помощи `js` используйте метод `setAttribute`:

```
 elem.setAttribute("contenteditable", value);
```

Comment: Чтобы обновлять данные в базе, надо каждому td задать id? Я правильно понимаю? К примеру, `<td id="33">значение</td>`. Чтобы в sql-запросе было `...WHERE id=33`

Comment: @forever_young не уверен, все зависит от структуры базы

Comment: А какие варианты?) Я начинающий...

Comment: И еще вопрос. Я делаю mysql-запрос "SELECT id, item..." и затем вывожу таблицу с данными. Как добавить атрибут `contenteditable` только для тех `<td>`, где будет `item` (соответственно, для `<td>`, где `id` не нужно)?

Comment: По Вашим уточняющим вопросом все равно мало понятно что есть и что не так

Comment: Таблица, которая выводится, имеет всего два столбца id и item. Да и то, id  не сильно нужен. Получается на выводе один столбец. Хотел по двойному клику ставить курсор в строки единственного столбца, чтобы вручную допечатать или удалить символы.  Когда курсор покидает строку, нужно обновить значения в базе. Атрибут contenteditable похоже облегчает задачу. Но данные выводятся циклом. Поэтому я так понял, нужно задать каждому `<td>` id, чтобы по этому id обновлять строки в базе данных.